# A rope wrapping around a cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

> A massless rope of length $l$ is attached tangentially to a cylinder of radius $R$ and the free end of the rope is attached to a point mass $M$. When the rope is taut, the point mass is given an initial velocity $v_0$ perpendicular to the rope. All motion occurs on a horizontal frictionless surface.

How can we find the amount of time it takes for the point mass to reach the surface of the cylinder?

Comment: What are your ideas as to how this problem should be answered?

Comment: I already solved it, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler solution. Noting $P$ the point of contact between the rope and the cylinder, and $P_0$ the initial position of $P$, and $theta$ the angle between $P$ and $P_0$, we need to find the equation verified by $theta$. Do this by using the relation $l=l_0+R\theta$,etc

Comment: What's your final answer? I know a simple way to solve this, but I don't want to do your homework for you.

Comment: My final answer us is $l^2/(2Rv_0)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here's a simple solution then.

The force due to the tension of the rope is always perpendicular to the velocity, so it does not change the energy of the particle, and so the velocity is always $v_0$.

The angular velocity about the point of contact is $\omega=v_0/(l-R\theta)$ since $l-R\theta$ is the length between point of contact and particle as you pointed out.

The final angular position of the particle is $l/R$, so the total time $t$,
$$t=\int^{l/R}_0\frac{dt}{d\theta}d\theta=\int^{l/R}_0\omega^{-1}d\theta=\frac{1}{v_0}\int^{l/R}_0(l-R\theta)d\theta=\frac{1}{v_0}(l(l/R)-\frac{R}{2}(l/R)^2)=\frac{l^2}{2Rv_0}$$